# String searching algorithm - Complexity of string matching

Tags: python, string, algorithm, md5

I am trying to solve for **'String search algorithm'** but the answers of many sites seems to be complex ( **'Naive string search'** with  **O(m(n-m+1)** ), what's the issue with my algo below, it has worst case complexity of O(n), while **KMP** also has **O(n)** therefore I must be definitely wrong, but where?

```
def find(s1, s2):
    size = len(s1)
    index = 0 
    while ( index != len(s2)):
        if s2[index : index + size] == s1:
            print 'Pattern found at index %s'%(index)
            index += size
        else:
            index += 1
```

Ok so I was supposing `s2[index : index + size] == s1` to be O(1) which is O(n), so now my original question becomes,

- Why isn't the hashes of two strings calculated and compared, if both hashes are equal strings should be equal.
- I don't get how can they collide. Isn't that dependant of hashing algorithm. Like `MD5` has known breaks.

Comment: You're assuming `s2[index : index + size] == s1` is O(1). Is it?

Comment: How would the hash of `s2[index:index+size]` be computed in less than O(len(s1)) time? It's possible to do this using a rolling hash (which is exactly what Rabin-Karp does), but you seem to suggesting that python should somehow do this for you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm covers this.

Comment: @PaulHankin thx, naive for me to assume string searching is so simple, just blink and done. Let me spend some time reading their years of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Original question

I don't think your code has complexity O(n), but rather O(mn). This check: `s2[index : index + size] == s1`, since, in the worst case, it needs to do `len(s1)` comparisons of characters.

---

## Hashing

Here's [Wikipedia's definition of a hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function):

> A hash function is any function that can be used to map data of
> arbitrary size to data of fixed size. The values returned by a hash
> function are called hash values, hash codes, digests, or simply
> hashes. One use is a data structure called a hash table, widely used in computer software for rapid data lookup.

Here we run into the first problem with this approach. A hash function takes in a value of arbitrary size, and returns a value of a fixed size. Following the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there is at least one hash with multiple values, probably more. As a quick example, imagine your hash function always produces an output that is one byte long. That means there are 256 possible outputs. After you've hashed 257 items, you'll always be certain there are at least 2 items with the same hash. To avoid this for as long as possible, a good hash function will map inputs over all possible outputs as [uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Uniformity) as possible.

So if the hashes aren't equal, you can be sure the strings aren't equal, but not vice versa. **Two different strings can have the same hash.**

Comment: ok, so for string comparison complexity is O(n), but why it is so, can't one calculate the hashes of both string and compare, that would be O(1)

Comment: @garg10may Yes, but the hashes might collide, so you're looking at an algorithm that runs in time O(n) expected, not worst case, and it already has a name: Rabin--Karp.

Comment: I don't know much about the internals of hashing algorithms, but since one of the properties of a hash is that it should change if any of the characters in the string changes, you need to look at all the characters in a string to compute a hash, meaning it's at least `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the string you're hashing. Also, the hash of a string doesn't tell you anything about hashes of substrings, so you'd have to do that for all substrings of length `m`.

Comment: aren't hashes supposed to be unique for unique strings?

Comment: That depends. Most hashes have a fixed number of bits, whereas a string can have an arbitrary length. In mathematical terms, you're mapping a countably infinite set (all possible strings) to a finite set (all possible hashes of length k). Actually, now that I think of it, I'm not sure whether there are variable length hashes.